# CI-file upload, error-showing-if/else causes image duplication

Tags: codeigniter, image-processing, if-statement

I had somehow managed to upload and resize multiple images, everything was fine.
 Then i wanted to show errors if no image was selected to upload.
I put a if statement to load the error but that's causing a havoc.

Each time i select images and upload, the last one gets duplicated, without resizing.
Again, if i remove the if else, it's perfectly fine.

Thankyou for any help and your time.

```
function do_upload(){


    $path = array();
    $count = count($_FILES['userfile']['size']);

    foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value){
        for($n=0; $n<=$count-1; $n++) {
            $_FILES['userfile']['name']=$value['name'][$n];
            $_FILES['userfile']['type']    = $value['type'][$n];
            $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$n];
            $_FILES['userfile']['error']       = $value['error'][$n];
            $_FILES['userfile']['size']    = $value['size'][$n];   

                $config['upload_path'] = './images';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->do_upload();
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $path[] = $data['full_path'];
        }   



        if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('view_dashboard_error_car', $error);
        }
        else{
            $this->load->library('image_lib');   

            foreach($path as $p=>$ath){
                $config1 = array(
                'source_image'      => $ath,
                'new_image'         => './images',
                'maintain_ration'   => true,
                'overwrite'         => true, 
                'width'             => 600,
                'height'            => 400
                );

                $this->image_lib->initialize($config1);
                $this->image_lib->resize();
                $this->image_lib->clear();
            }       



            $this->load->view('view_dashboard_success_car');

        }





    }   




}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running `$this->upload->do_upload()` twice, because your `foreach()` runs and then your `if/else` statement runs.

You need to put the `if/else` into your `foreach` loop. You should take care not to just copy/paste it in, but make sure you're only running `$this->upload->do_upload()` once per image.

Comment: Ok, you're still running it twice. Can you not see that? `foreach` and `for` are loops. Anything that you need to run inside the loop must be within the loop. An if/else statement outside of it will run only once, and is not tied to the loop. This is why your loop runs, then your if/else runs after it, causing only the last item to be checked.

Comment: ya, i even put it inside the for loop, but it makes it even more worse, it resizes all images and duplicates all(without resizing), and then loads the `view_dashboard_success-car` twice, two templates one above another.

Comment: I don't mean offense when I say this, but if you look at your code... it's quite obvious what is happening. It might help if you read it aloud to yourself. Your logic essentially says, "for every image, set these variables, load the image library, and run this if/else statement". You must realize that if the "if" portion is satisfied, it's going to load the view, and if the "else" portion is satisified... it's ALSO going to load the view, because that is what your code is telling PHP to do.

Comment: Hey, so can you please tell me/edit that code, i've tried everything you said.  Why only the last one gets duplicated, all others get resized and uploaded fine.